# javascript regexp for word boundary detection with parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string "I am a robot, I have been named 456/m(4). Forget the name (it does not mean anything)"

Now I would like to extract all words from this string
for this I use the regular expression:

```
/\b[\w\S]+\b/g
```

it returns me all the words in the string except that there is a word "456/(4" instead of "456/(4)". I  understand that it is due to the fact that it is a word boundary, but is there a way I could say that it is not a legal word boundary since there was no "legal" starting parenthesis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made it even better now. It does exactly what you want.

```
\b(?>\([\w\/]+\)|[\w\/])+
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iX0iP1/6)

If you want a version that's javascript friendly:

```
((?:(?=(\([\w\/]+\)|[\w\/]))\2)+)
```

Just use capture group #1 here.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iX0iP1/7)

Comment: I am sorry but this doesnt seem to be working for say "exposed to 360J/m(2) and 456/m(4)" I beleive my question is more generic that this quick fix solution you proposed.

Comment: @suzee I just updated it to work better for you. I was busy so I couldn't get back sooner. Sorry!

Comment: @suzee i improved it even more. now it will only grab the parenthesis if it's a part of the word.

Comment: @suzee please don't make wrong edits. No one on this site actually checks the validity of the edits so it'll get through. I added a correct javascript friendly version to the answer for you.